# how to go to next screen after google sign in

Tags: android, google-authentication

I am using google sign in api to login it is working all fine but i am stuck at how to go to the next activity or screen after successful login

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

//Signin button
private SignInButton signInButton;

//Signing Options
private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

//google api client
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

//Signin constant to check the activity result
private int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

//TextViews
private TextView textViewName;
private TextView textViewEmail;
private NetworkImageView profilePhoto;

//Image Loader
private ImageLoader imageLoader;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing Views
    textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
    textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
    profilePhoto = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

    //Initializing google signin option
    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    //Initializing signinbutton
    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
    signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

    //Initializing google api client
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


    //Setting onclick listener to signing button
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}


//This function will option signing intent
private void signIn() {
    //Creating an intent
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

    //Starting intent for result
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //If signin
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        //Calling a new function to handle signin
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}


//After the signing we are calling this function
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    //If the login succeed
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        //Getting google account
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

        //Displaying name and email
        textViewName.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
        textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());

        //Initializing image loader
        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
                .getImageLoader();

        imageLoader.get(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePhoto,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

        //Loading image
        profilePhoto.setImageUrl(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(), imageLoader);

    } else {
        //If login fails
        Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == signInButton) {
        //Calling signin
        signIn();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
android:id="@+id/profileImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
android:text="Name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewName"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
android:text="email"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

i just wanted to know where i can add the next activity on click og google sign in after sucessfull login it will show name email id and image of that particular person how to go to next screen after 5 seconds of login after displaying the image email id and name

Comment: you can launch next after getting success in handleSignInResult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In handleSignInResult function, you can call another activity if you got sucess result.

You can use handler for 5 seconds delay. Write below code after Loading image line.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
         Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, OtherActivityName.class);
         startActivity(mainIntent);
     }
 }, 5000);
```

Comment: where should i use this new Handler

Comment: In handleSignInResult function, in if (result.isSuccess()) {} after Loading image line.

Comment: it is coming cant resolve symbol Handler

Comment: i have used after profilePhoto.setImageUrl(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(), imageLoader);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {

Comment: have you import require package for handler?

Comment: i m getting cant resolve symbol handler

Comment: which all are the required package for handler

Comment: Use CTRL + SHIFT + O

Comment: ctrl + shift + O doesnt do anything

Comment: In Studio , For Windows/Linux, you can go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Java and make the following changes: change Insert imports on paste value to All. mark Add unambigious imports on the fly option as checked.

Comment: i directly added android.os.Handler it is working now thank you.

Answer (score 1):

StartActivity inside  handleSignInResult  method after  result.isSuccess()

```
   if (result.isSuccess()) {
    //Getting google account
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

    //Displaying name and email
    textViewName.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
    textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());

    //Initializing image loader
    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
            .getImageLoader();

    imageLoader.get(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(profilePhoto,
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher));

    //Loading image
    profilePhoto.setImageUrl(acct.getPhotoUrl().toString(), imageLoader);
    Intent nextactivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), newclass.class);
    startActivity(nextactivity);


} else {
    //If login fails
    Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

update some delay before going to next activity

```
   new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
     Intent nextactivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), newclass.class);
    startActivity(nextactivity);
                  }
              }, 5000);
```

Comment: this is working but i need some delay before going to next activity

Comment: check my update answer

Answer (score 1):

You can add the next activity class in handleSignInResult method when login success.

```
//If the login succeed
if (result.isSuccess()) {
    //Add your next activity in here
       startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,NextActivity.class));

} else {
    //If login fails
    Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

For display Google Account name in your next Activity, you can add this code:
in MainActivity class

```
handleSignInResult(){
//Displaying name and email 
String personName = acct.getDisplayName(); 
textViewName.setText(personName); 
textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());
```

`Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class); 
i.putExtra("name", personName); 
startActivity(i); 
}`

And add this code for the receiver class NextActivity:

```
String name;
```

`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) { name = extras.getDouble("name"); }`

Comment: it is going to next activity but i need user to be there on that screen for atleast 5 seconds

Comment: In your class MainActivity add some code like this:

Comment: //Displaying name and email
        String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
        textViewName.setText(personName);
        textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());
        
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name", personName);
        startActivity(i);

And add this code for the receiver class NextActivity:
                String name;
                Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                if(extras !=null) {
                    name = extras.getDouble("name");
                }

Answer (score 1):

You can start "countdowntimer" of 5 second when user press "Google Sign In" button once user is logged in successfully then you can fill data in a variable and the after 5 second "countdowntimer" will invoke method "onFinish" from there you can send user to next screen.

Answer (score 0):

you should create another class called LoginActivity maybe, and add that to your manifest.

Take a look here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.FullScreen" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```